# GWT - Get dom element's value from another page

Tags: java, gwt

Suppose I have two pages `A.jsp` and `B.jsp`. I have few elements on both the pages which has been generated through `GWT` code. Now I want to get the value of a element which is there on `A.jsp` while I'm sending a request through `B.jsp` and I want to pass that value into the request header.
I'm generating a request with:

`RequestBuilder rb = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, queryUrl);`

I have tried using `getElement()` [getElement](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiDom.html) however it is giving the elements which are there on that.

I want to access elements from other pages. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this was possible, than theoretically any website would be able to get any data from any other page open in a browser, including credit card numbers, passwords, etc. Fortunately, it's not possible.

If you need to share data between different apps/pages that you control, you need to use a browser cookie, a server session, or a database/datastore to store this data. In other words, when something happens on page B, store this data somewhere where an app running in page A can access it.